# What are the rules for struct auto defined constructors in c++ 17?

Tags: c++, struct, c++17

Given:

```
struct X {
  int m;
  std::string s;
};
```

I can do:

```
X x;  // invokes automatically defined default ctor
X y = { 5 };   // invokes whatever became of the original struct initialization but now maybe runs through C++ initializer-lists?
X z = { 5, "yolo" };  // I assume this is an initializer-list that is being handled by some rule for structs that either runs through a compiler created ctor or copy-from-initializer-list that is similarly compiler-created
```

and even...

```
std::vector<X> vx;
vx.push_back({ 99, "yo" }); // okay
```

But not...

```
vx.emplace_back(99, "yo");  // error VS 2017 v. 15.7.4
vx.emplace_back({99, "yo"});  // error VS 2017 v. 15.7.4
```

I'm not understanding the rules between initializer-lists, implicitly defined (or compiler defined) ctors, and forwarding functions like `emplace_back()`

Would someone be so kind as to either point me to the necessary bits of the standard or a good article on an in-depth discussion of what's become of all of the rules around structs and implicit construction and other compiler-supplied members such as copy / move operators?

I seem to be in need of a more comprehensive rules lesson - because it seems like `emplace_back()` ought to work for one of either `emplace_back(int, std::string)`, or for `emplace_back(initializer-list)` - no?

Comment: `X y = { 5 };` is an [aggregate initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), not a constructor (call). There is no default defined constructor taking 2 parameters.(which `emplace_back` requires)

Comment: It's a lot of minutiae: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X` is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). While the specific definition of aggregate has changed in every standard, your type is an aggregate in all of them.

List-initialization for an aggregate does aggregate-initialization here. There's no constructor here - there's no "auto" constructor, no synthesized constructor. Aggregate-initialization does not create constructors or go through that mechanism. We're directly initializing each class member from the appropriate initializer in the *braced-init-list*. That's what both your `y` and your `z` are doing.

Now, for the second part. The relevant part of `vector` looks like:

```
template <typename T>
struct vector {
    void push_back(T&&);

    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&...);
};
```

A *braced-init-list*, like `{99, "yo"}`, does not have a type. And you cannot deduce a type for it. They can only be used in specific circumstances. `push_back({99, "yo"})` works fine because `push_back` takes an `X&&` - it's not a function template - and we know how to do that initialization.

But `emplace_back()` is a function template - it needs to deduce `Args...` from the types of its arguments. But we don't have a type, there's nothing to deduce! There are some exceptions here (notably `std::initializer_list<T>` can be deduced), but here, we're stuck. You would have to write `emplace_back(X{99, "yo"})` - which creates the `X` on the caller's side.

Similarly, `emplace_back(99, "yo")` doesn't work because `emplace` uses `()`s to initialize, but you cannot `()`-initialize an aggregate. It doesn't have a constructor!